# TAB navigation to flow through stacked layers in a webpage (z-index)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click of an `input` field, a projected `popup window` opens (have used `z-index`). 
Now when i press `TAB`, i want the `focus` to automatically move from background screen to the popped up window.

Is it possible to achieve this flow of `TAB` navigation through built in properties or styling ?

NOTE 1: I tried setting `focus` to the outer `div` of the `popup` programatically.
So that the focus is moved from background to popup. 
But it fails in `IE11` and `IE10` because, the cursor remains in one element and the focus remains in another element when navigation passes through an empty field. I DONOT WANT HELP FROM COMMUNITY MEMBERS TO DEBUG THIS CODE.

NOTE 2: I won't be able to set the `tabindex` for the `popup` window elements statically. Because in that case, the `TAB` moves to those elements even when the `popup` window is not visible.

Comment: Where are you having issues, add that code.

Comment: Post your current code please.

Comment: A code or a fiddle would be helpful

Comment: I am not expecting help with regard to the code. I just want to know if it is possible to achieve navigation flow through multiple layers using any built in properties/styling.